# Mystery Character Is Not Quite A Tab

Tags: csv, character-encoding, tabs

I'm working with what looks like a tab-delimited file, only the character does not seem to be a tab.  Here's some output of my python session (not sure what the character will be once posted through this system):

```
>>> line = 'ISBN    COPY    AUTHOR_BIO  QUOTE   EXCERPT TABLE_OF_CONTENT'
>>> line
'ISBNCOPYAUTHOR_BIOQUOTEEXCERPTTABLE_OF_CONTENT'
>>> '\t' in 'ISBN   COPY    AUTHOR_BIO  QUOTE   EXCERPT TABLE_OF_CONTENT'
False
>>> '\u0009' in 'ISBN   COPY    AUTHOR_BIO  QUOTE   EXCERPT TABLE_OF_CONTENT'
False
```

Here I cut and paste the character (I'm running a python session using a shell in emacs):

```
>>> '   ' in '  '
True
>>> '   ' in 'ISBN  COPY    AUTHOR_BIO  QUOTE   EXCERPT TABLE_OF_CONTENT'
False
```

If I ask emacs to M-x eval-expression ?(mystery_char) it says: `9 (#o11, #x9, ?\C-i)`, and I've tried cutting a pasting it into websites that purport to identify the bytecode, they say it's a unicode tab U+0009.

I've solved my problem by just pasting the mystery character into a conf file, but I'd like to figure out what's going on with it.

**UPDATE**
I think part of my issue in debugging is that i'm running the python interpreter in an emacs inferior shell, if I use a terminal, then cut-and-pasting the problem line results in showing '\t's between the words.  Not sure why, or why the following code doesn't work with '\t':

```
delimiter = self.get_delimiter()
csv_fieldnames_line = csv_lines.pop(0)
csv_fieldnames = csv_fieldnames_line.split(delimiter)
print(f"delimiter is '{delimiter}' and csv_fieldnames_line is '{csv_fieldnames_line}' and csv_fieldnames is {csv_fieldnames}")
```

result:
`delimiter is '\t' and csv_fieldnames_line is 'ISBN COPY    AUTHOR_BIO  QUOTE   EXCERPT TABLE_OF_CONTENT' and csv_fieldnames is ['ISBN\tCOPY\tAUTHOR_BIO\tQUOTE\tEXCERPT\tTABLE_OF_CONTENT']`

If I replace the \t with the actual tab from the file, I get the following result:
`delimiter is ' ' and csv_fieldnames_line is 'ISBN  COPY    AUTHOR_BIO  QUOTE   EXCERPT TABLE_OF_CONTENT' and csv_fieldnames is ['ISBN', 'COPY', 'AUTHOR_BIO', 'QUOTE', 'EXCERPT', 'TABLE_OF_CONTENT']`

Comment: Try `from urllib.parse import quote; quote(line)` and share the output…

Comment: `>>> line = 'ISBN COPY AUTHOR_BIO QUOTE EXCERPT TABLE_OF_CONTENT'

>>> from urllib.parse import quote; quote(line)
'ISBNCOPYAUTHOR_BIOQUOTEEXCERPTTABLE_OF_CONTENT'`

I think these are just tab characters--so maybe it's my understanding of how python treats them that it is out of whack!

Comment: Updated my main post with more info